# How do nested for loops work when it comes to printing?

Tags: java, printing

```
public static void printArrayAsStars(int[] array) {
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("*");
        for(int j = 0; j < array[i] - 1; j++){
            System.out.print("*" + "");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Trying to figure out how this prints is confusing when I try to work this out on paper. I'm aware that the outer for loop prints the rows, but how does the inner for loop work and position the stars in this position?

```
*****
*
***
****
**
```

If they both have the same statement `System.out.print()` then how does one print rows and the other one print columns? Does the last line have something to do with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`println` doesn't visibly change anything; it 'ends the line', and means that any print statements executed later will start on a new line.

So, the outer loop will print a single star every time it is invoked, then do whatever the inner loop does, then prints a newline. In other words, every 'outer loop' gets its own line, and every outer loop means you get 1 star at least.

Then the inner loop prints X-1 stars, where X is the value of array[i]. Given that the outer loop always prints a star, that means every line is stars equal to array[i], with the additional caveat that at least 1 star is printed, even if array[i] is 0 or negative.

And that's that.

So, your array here must therefore be 5 in length, and its values are:

```
int[] array = {5, 1, 3, 4, 2}; // the 1 could be 0 or negative too for the same result.
```

Answer (score 2):

The crux of it is `print` versus `println`.

```
System.out.print("*");
System.out.print("*" + "");
```

Both of these statements print a single `*` character and move the cursor one column to the right. (They do the exact same thing because the `+ ""` bit is superfluous. Concatenating an empty string to another string is a [no-op](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/no-op-no-operation).)

```
System.out.println();
```

This statement moves the cursor to the next row and reset it to the first column. In other words, it ends the current line and starts a new one.

The overall effect is that the inner loop prints a line of stars, leaving the cursor at the end, and the final `println()` moves on to the next line. Hence, each iteration of the outer loop prints a row of stars.